# Is there a way for jinja to output its partially rendered content before an exception?

Tags: python, jinja2

If I get an exception during rendering in Jinja I get a stack track showing what line the exception arose at in the template. In my situation this is in a for loop that's iterating over many values. It would be nice if Jinja could communicate what value it was on when the exception occurred. Is there any means to get Jinja to output partially rendered templates or to have it trace what it was about to render?

I'm seeing a stacktrace like the following due to a string somehow showing up where a float is expected.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/USER_X/test.py", line 137, in result2Html
    with open( css_path ) as cssFile :
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Jinja2-2.10-py2.7.egg/jinja2/environment.py", line 1008, in render
    return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Jinja2-2.10-py2.7.egg/jinja2/environment.py", line 780, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "<template>", line 43, in top-level template code
ValueError: Unknown format code '%' for object of type 'str'
```

Comment: I was facing somewhat similar issues and created a tool to swallow Jinja2 errors and print out partial templates, might worth having a look. It knows a bit more than just using `jinja2.DebugUndefined`. https://gist.github.com/zsltg/a3ed05e0a36051e1ecc4a49f3b1c2b82